# What's a half-man?

Tags: vocabulary

I found a lot of meanings for "half-man", like a drinking game, a dealer... None seems to fit in this sentence. Could you help me please?

> He could not understand why these fathers, half-men all, could stand idly by and watch their young daughters march off to school and to the mall and into the cars of quick-handed boys wearing clothing more appropriate for a strip club than for public view.

Comment: Could you provide the source? Is it a novel? (Aside: I'm kinda guessing that it might end up meaning something like "not much of a man" or "less than a man" but for the plural "men". That is, the narrator doesn't think much of those fathers, for the narrator doesn't think that true men ("full men") would allow that kind of behavior by their daughters.)

Comment: It is a novel called Break my Heart a Thousand Times. And I think you're right. Thanks

Comment: *[I'm not half the man I used to be](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNnaxGFO18o)*- "Yesterday"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author is using half-man to belittle the fathers.

Reason, he is a man so he can make a daughter biologically. However, he is not a man because he doesn't have any responsibility.

He is only half of a man.